# Read all Azure AD users with Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to read all users from my Azure AD with Graph with the following method:

```cs
public void GetUsers() {

    var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create("my application id")
        .WithTenantId("my tenant id")
        .WithClientSecret("my application secret")
        .Build();

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta", new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClient));

    var request = graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("accountEnabled eq true");

    var users = await request.GetAsync(); // throws exception!
}
```

When I execute `request.GetAsync()` I receive the following exception:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-08-26T14:25:27",
      "request-id": "d2772ea1-a994-4f14-bfad-0baffc6d24d3",
      "client-request-id": "my application id"
    }
  }
}
```

On Azure AD I created an application, and I added over "API permissions" these permissions `Read.User.All` and `Read.User`

Do I need another specific permission? It's coding error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure permission type is "Application" and not "Delegated" and Status shows "Granted for "

If you see status as "Not granted" , click on "Grant admin consent"